# How to fix sudo due to pam error

Tags: command-line, ssh, login, sudo, authentication

The short story is that I can SSH into my device with the a username and password that should be in the superuser group (so I should be able to `sudo su`). The problem is that I was trying to increase the user open file limits and I edited `/etc/pam.d/common-session-interactive`. I was supposed to enter this line:

```
session required pam_limits.so
```

but I stupidly entered this line instead:

```
session_required pam_limits.so
```

Note the underscore between session and required. Unfortunately, the `sudo` setup apparently tries to load the file `/etc/pam.d/common-session-interactive` and I think it is getting to that line and failing. Also unfortunately, that file is owned by root and is read only. So, to fix my `sudo su` problem, I need `sudo su` to work so I can change that file! Any ideas on how I can edit this file and fix the problem?

Comment: Can you use a Live CD/USB to access the file to change it back?

Comment: if you have root password, you can just `su`. `sudo su` is not the only thing in Linux.

Comment: First try su without sudo.

Can you provide the missing file with what it thinks it needs?

Comment: Another work around is booting a usb or cd to edit the file, then reboot again.

Comment: We ended up just reinstalling the OS on the machine. It was an embedded device so there was not critical persistent data. Glad it wasn't a cloud server.

Answer (score 0):

Use su without sudo to correct the mistaken text file entry. The real root user can perform the task without using the sudo system